# Polynomial hash code results in negative numbers?

Tags: c++, math, hash

For large j in certain cases functions the hash function below returns negative values.

```
int hashing::hash(string a)
{
    int i = 0;
    int hvalue = 0;
    int h =0 ;
    while(a[i]!=NULL)
    {
        hvalue = hvalue + (int(a[i]))*pow(31,i);
        i++;
    }
    h = hvalue%j;
    return h;
}
```

How is that possible? How can I correct it?

In the above code, j is a prime number calculated using the size of the file. The negative values arise in certain specific cases where the string has the form " the s".

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `int` has a finite range and is (usually) a signed value. That means that if you exceed the maximum possible value for an `int`, it will wrap around and might become negative.

There are a couple of ways you could fix that. First, you could switch to using `unsigned int`s to hold the hash code, which are never negative and will behave nicely when wrapping around. Alternatively, if you still want to use `int`s, you can mask off the sign bit (the bit at the front of the number that makes the value negative) by doing this:

```
return (hvalue & INT_MAX) % j;
```

(Here, `INT_MAX` is defined in `<climits>`). This will ensure your value is positive, though you lose a bit from your hash code, which might for large data sets lead to some more clustering. The reason for doing the `&` before the mod is that you want to ensure the value is positive before taking the mod, since otherwise you'll overflow the number of buckets.

**EDIT:** You also have a serious error in your logic.  This loops is incorrect:

```
while(a[i]!=NULL) {
    ...
}
```

C++-style strings aren't null-terminated, so this isn't guaranteed to stop once you read past the end of the string. Try changing this to read

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) { 
    /* ... process a[i] ... */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: using this i dont get a negative value but what i get is an error for maximum int value. how can i resolve that??

Comment: @user2648875- Did you `#include <climits>`?

Comment: yes. i no longer get a negative value but i get the value of INT_MAX

Comment: int hashing::hash(string a)
{
int i =0;
int hvalue = 0;
int h=0;
while(a[i]!=NULL)
    {
    hvalue = hvalue + (int(a[i]))*power(31,i);
    i++;
    }
h = hvalue%j;
 return h & INT_MAX;
}

Comment: @user2648875- What specific error are you getting? Can you elaborate? This seems to be working fine on my system.

Comment: printing out the value returned from this program for a certain string " the s" the value i am getting is 2147483546(this value was coming out to be negative earlier). This is causing my program to stall because i use this value as an index of an array

Comment: @user2648875- Oh, I see.  You need to reorder the modulus and the AND. Change the line to return `(hvalue & INT_MAX) % j`. That should fix things. (Also, please read the edit to my answer... there's another error you're making!)

Comment: thank you so much. it works. really appreciate your effort. it helped a lot.